# Numbers and Slash (Dates) only textbox asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex

I have a `gridview` that contains names and dates. I also placed some textbox on the header of the gridview that can be used for searching. I want my textbox for searching dates to restrict user from typing other characters than numbers and slash. So basically, I want a textbox that only allows users to type dates. It should allow the user to search by typing **Month**(01-12), **Month and Day**(01/13,12/30) or **Month, Day, and Year**(`01/13/2018`, `12/30/2018`)...

I used `TextMode: Date` on the textbox before but it requires the user to complete the full `mm/dd/yyyy` format which restricts users to search with just month or month and day only. I tried some javascripts I found in the internet but it doesn't meet my requirements. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kindly Use the below javascript which answers your Question

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title></title>
<style type="text/css">
        body
        {
          font-size: 9pt;
          font-family: Arial;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
Enter Date:
  <input type="text" id="text1" onkeypress="return IsValidData(event);" 
 ondrop="return false;"
    onpaste="return false;" />
<span id="error" style="color: Red; display: none">* Invalid Character</span>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var specialKeys = new Array();
    specialKeys.push(8); //Backspace
    specialKeys.push(9); //Tab
    specialKeys.push(46); //Delete
    specialKeys.push(36); //Home
    specialKeys.push(35); //End
    specialKeys.push(37); //Left
    specialKeys.push(39); //Right
    function IsValidData(e) {
        var keyCode = e.keyCode == 0 ? e.charCode : e.keyCode;
        var ret = ((keyCode >= 48 && keyCode <= 57) || (keyCode == 43) || (keyCode == 47) || (specialKeys.indexOf(e.keyCode) != -1 && e.charCode != e.keyCode));
        document.getElementById("error").style.display = ret ? "none" : "inline";
        return ret;
    }
</script>
```

If this POST answers your Question, please check the green tick.

Comment: I  copied and pasted your codes in my aspx page but nothing happens on the textbox.

Comment: Uhm, I literally copied and pasted your code to my page to test if it is working at first, but it's not. I copied the lines starting from input tag up to the closing tag of script.

Comment: just create a new sample web application and replace in the aspx page. I tried the same and it worked for me. please try and share the feedback

Comment: Hmmm. You're right it's working on my sample web page. This is strange. I'll go and check my main aspx page.

Comment: Oh my it seems like a typo error on my part. It's working now. Thank you very much.

Comment: btw, do you mind if you explain your answer a bit? I'm kind of confused on how it worked. I'm new to javascript and this is my first time seeing an array in a js.

Comment: The push() method adds new items to the end of an array and returns the new length.
This method changes the length of the array.
To add items at the beginning of an array, use the unshift() method.

Once we add these items to the array , we are checking with the keyboard keys on press and these 
keys which we given in the array will be allowed to do their actions. Other keys will not do any action if we press

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/168086/discussion-between-vivek-ramasamy-and-pau-gacusan).

Answer (score 1):

You could use Parse which is quite forgiving:

```
string s = "5/12";
DateTime d = DateTime.Parse(s);

// d will hold: 2018-12-05
```

Of course, wrap it in a try-catch.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`asp:RegularExpressionValidator`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650303.aspx) to validate a `TextBox`'s `Text` property.

In the example below, I used the `^\d{4}\/\d{2}\/\d{4}$` regular expression, which allows only positive numbers with slashes, as you required.

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txt1" runat="server"/>
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="myRegex" 
                                runat="server"     
                                ErrorMessage="Invalid characters." 
                                ControlToValidate="txt1"     
                                ValidationExpression="^\d{4}\/\d{2}\/\d{4}$" />
```

Comment: I typed 05, 05/12, 05/12/2016 and all of them are 'Invalid Characters'. And also, what I want is something that restricts users from typing anything aside from numbers or slash for dates.